# Speech Recognition PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, windows-8, speech-recognition, windows-server-2012

I'm running a sample using speech recognition and it´s not working on windows 8 or 2012 server.

Using win8 or win2012server the following code doesn´t return records, but it does in win7.

```
foreach(RecognizerInfo rec in System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rec.Culture);
    }
```

If I use a LoadGrammar using win8 or win2012 server it raises an exception:

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammar (new Grammar (new GrammarBuilder (new Choices (_numbersGrammar.Keys.ToArray ()))) { Name = "Numbers_Grammar" });
```

'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' saying that no recognizer was installed.

StackTrace:

> System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.Initialize(SapiRecognizer
>   recognizer, Boolean inproc)    em
>   System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.get_RecoBase()    em
>   System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(Grammar
>   grammar)    em SpeechRecognition.CaptchaSpeechManager..ctor(Int32
>   lettersCount, Int32 waitMilliseconds) in
>   ....cs:line
>   289    em SpeechRecognition.Program.Main(String[] args) na
>   e:\TestCenter\SpeechRecognition\SpeechRecognition\Program.cs:linha 24 
>   em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    in
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    em
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    em
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    em
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

What do I have to install? I tried to install Speech SDK 11 but it closes until completition oO

Does anybody know any incompatibility with this OSs?

Does anybody know another lib to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `System.Speech` namespace which is used for Speech SDK 5.3/5.4, while you should be using `Microsoft.Speech` which is the Speech SDK 11 one and you can find its assembly in

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Assembly\Microsoft.Speech.dll"

if you install it to the default path.